# Don't call the ItemListener at adding a Item to a JavaComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I have a JavaComboBox and a ItemListner on this ComboBox. 
These ItemListener is called every time i add a Item to the ComboBox with addItem().
Is there a way to dont call thise ItemListner by adding a Item?

Comment: Remove the item listener from the combo box?

Comment: I need the ITemListene to ListenListener to listen for a new selected item but not at adding a item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean to temporarily disable a listener.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722835/how-to-temporarily-disable-event-listeners-in-) is something useful.

I think a flag is good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now use a flag (this idea occurs to me after writing the question =) ). I see no other way for the problem.