# Behind the scene action listeners in Java MVC designs

Tags: java, model-view-controller, action, actionlistener

We are discussing MVC design for Java.  The statement was read that there are behind the scene actions and listeners that cause the view to update when the the Model is updated.  We are also taught that all the interaction we program into our MVC design should be between the controller and Model, controller and view.  Never between the View and Model.  Does the built in classes follow this as well, where the dataUpdated action is caught by the Controller and in turn the controller updates the View?  Or do the behind scene actions get caught directly by the view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The MVC pattern and SWING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing)

Comment: Or this question: [Is there something wrong with Swing's MVC implementation for JList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716072/is-there-something-wrong-with-swings-mvc-implementation-for-jlist)

Comment: Shoot just check out [these links](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+do+swing+components+follow+mvc).