# java DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing

```
if(incasationBegin > 0)
{
  int anwser = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, Config.QUESTION,"Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
  if(anwser == 1)
  {
      jList0.setSelectedIndex(incasationBegin);
      return;
  }
}
incasationBegin = jList0.getSelectedIndex();
```

How do I `setSelectedIndex` *without calling* `jList0ListSelectionValueChanged` action? Because when I click on option confirm popup and when I click NO, the new item is still selected. I have tried to add `incasationBegin =0;` before return, but then on first click confirm popup.

Comment: Even with the code and explanation, I still don't follow you. Can you please elaborate or make your explanation more clear/concise?

Comment: after calling `jList0.setSelectedIndex(incasationBegin);` this the action `jList0ListSelectionValueChanged` is called, and I dont want that, is it possible ??

Comment: Well, `valueChanged` is triggered whenever selection/deselection is done. So, not wanting this to happen seems very unnatural. Anyway, a little bit of browsing landed me the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092834/can-i-set-the-selected-item-for-a-jlist-without-having-an-event-thrown-to-the-lis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if i understood you correctly. You are adding a `ListSelectionListener` to the `JList` and want to prevent your call to `setSelectedIndex` from firing  the `valueChanged` event, is that it?

You can try a lot of different approaches here:

1. Delay your call to `jList0.addListSelectionListener(...` in such way that no Listener exists when you call `setSelectedIndex`.
2. Have the listener `valueChanged` method check for some "enabled condition", for example read a `boolean isEnabled`. Set this condition to false before calling `setSelectedIndex` and to true after that.
3. Call `jList0.removeListSelectionListener(..` before the call to `setSelectedIndex`. Add the listener to the list again after the call.